# Find "developer name" to link to your apps in the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Kind of a derp question but...

I reactivated my developer account I had several years ago. I am wanting to release my apps under my company name that I have started, but as of right now I don't know if it will display under my own name.

A) Where in the iTunes dev portal can I find what title will display under apps I release to the app store

and

B) Where is my "developer name" in the dev portal? When you link to apps, you would do something like :

```
NSString *dibAppsURL = @"itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/developername";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dibAppsURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

I am unsure as to what my developer name is. Sorry, I know :-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) In iTC, look under contracts. You'll see the legal entity. This is not guaranteed to be what is shown in iTunes however. When you submit your first app, the first step is to set what your Developer name will be (at least with a company account, not sure if that's the case with an individual account**). Most of the time you will set it to something similar to the legal entity. I've just checked several of my client accounts, and the only one that was different had a comma in the legal entity, but not on the App Store. Note that after you set your developer name that first time, you can not change it without getting someone at Apple to change it for you.

[image: Set your company name]

b) The developer link will be in this format:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/DEVNAME/idDEVID?mt=8

** I recommend avoiding using a personal account. Always use a company account. It costs the same, and has additional features (such as adding other developers).